# Supressing Java Exception Stack Trace

Tags: java

I wrote a script in Java to download data from a third party SOAP API.  I have to make many requests to this API in order to get all of the data that I need.  The third party SOAP API gives me errors every now and then.  The error it gives me is `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid date/time` which occurs when I used the code generated from the WSDL to read the SOAP reply.  When this happens, I add that particular request to a list of requests to try again, and after I try the first batch of requests, I continually re-try the requests that failed until all of the requests succeed.

I catch the exceptions, but they still output stack-traces to the console whenever they occur.  This is a problem because I am emailing the output of the Java program to a non-technical person, and the stack-traces just fill the email with information irrelevant to it's recipient.  Is there anyway to suppress these stack traces?  I know I could just send the email from Java instead of emailing the output of the Java program, but I would think that there should be some way of suppressing the stack traces which would be simpler considering I already have the output of my Java program being sent as an email using mailx.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I am not printing the stack trace.  Here is a generalized version of my code:

```
class Updater {
    static Stream<Datum> update(Collection<Datum> data) {
        data.parallelStream().map(datum -> Client.update(datum));
    }
}

class Client {
    static Datum update(Datum datum) {
        Request = new Request();
        return processRequest(request, datum);
    }

    static Datum processRequest(Request request, Datum datum) {
        Reply reply = null;
        try {
            reply = new ServiceLocator().getServicePort(new URL(endpointAddress)).getUpdates(request);
            update(datum, reply);
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warning("There was en error reading the response for " + datum);
        }
        return route;
    }
}
```

My logger logs to a file, not to the console.  My file has 2500 lines that look like:

```
There was an error reading the response for detail x and distinction y.
```

Meanwhile the output in my email has about 20 errors that look like this:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid date/time
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid date/time
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.onEndElement(SimpleDeserializer.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializerImpl.endElement(DeserializerImpl.java:502)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:171)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.vendor.stub.ServiceSoapBindingStup.getUpdates(ServiceBindingStup.java.2364)
    at com.mycompany.Client.processRequest(Client.java.16)
    at com.mycompany.Client.update(Client.java.10)
    at com.mycompany.Updater.lambda$update$0(Updater.java.2)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceTask.doLeaf(ReduceOps.java:747)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceTask.doLeaf(ReduceOps.java:721)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractTask.compute(AbstractTask.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid date/time
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.CalendarDeserializer.makeValue(CalendarDeserializer.java:75)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.onEndElement(SimpleDeserializer.java:172)
    ... 26 more
```

EDIT:

It's not ideal, but I dealt with this by writing the output of my Java program to standard error and I emailed standard error instead of standard output.  The stack traces were being written to standard output only.

Comment: Are you not printing the exceptions? Please share your code.

Comment: Do exceptions automatically print to STDERR?  Maybe redirect that?  How are you capturing output to email?  How are you handling exceptions?

Comment: @shmosel No I'm not.  Sorry I didn't attach code earlier, I just attached code.

Comment: @David It seems that the exception is printing to STDERR, but I catch all of the exceptions, so it shouldn't be happening.  I'm using the output of STDERR for other exceptions that are not supposed to happen.  I redirect the output of STDERR and STDOUT to email using crontab.

Comment: @David, thank you so much for your comment, you helped me find a work-around!  It turns out that the stack traces were being written so standard output, and I know it's not ideal, but I dealt with my problem by writing my normal output to standard error and then only emailing standard error.

Answer (score 0):

You could try three options:

Option 1) Don't print the exception when you catch it.

```
try {
    //some code
} catch(SomeException e) {
    //You might be printing the exception here like e.printStackTrace(). Remove those lines of code
}
```

Option 2) Write exceptions to a different file and normal output to another file, like so:

```
try {
    //your code
} catch(SomeException e) {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("exceptions.txt")));
    // print exception
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("normaloutput.txt")));
}
```

Option 3) Use printStackTrace method in the following manner (in case your java code is multi-threaded):

```
PrintStream errorStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("exceptions.txt"));
try {
    //your code
} catch(SomeException e) {
    // print exception to your stream
    e.printStackTrace(errorStream);
}
// no need of finally block
```

Comment: Changes to stdout and strerr are global and could affect other threads - the versions of `printStackTrace()` which accept `PrintStream` and `PrintWriter` seem more suited to the use case at hand (also, IIRC `printStrackTrace` prints to syserr rather than sysout)

Comment: I didn't factor in thread-safety actually :) ... do you mean to say that instead of setOut, we should be passing the PrintStream object to the printStackTrace method?

Comment: @giorgiga, I added option 3 ... that is what you meant, right?

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for trying to help!  I'm not printing the exception.  Sorry I didn't include code earlier; I just added it.